# Rails 3 jQuery UI Slider

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I'm trying to use the jQuery UI Slider with my rails 3 app.  I've downloaded a theme and put the css file in app/assets/stylesheet and I put all the images in app/assets/images.

When I load a page with a slider, I get an error that it can't find an image:

```
GET http://10.1.10.100:3000/assets/images/ui-bg_glass_45_0078ae_1x400.png 404 (Not Found)
```

That file is in app/assets/images/ and the css file has been edited to point to `../images/<image>`

Is there something else I need to do to make a jQuery slider work with Rails 3?

gist with the files:
https://gist.github.com/2355571

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to keep the jQuery UI files as they are, and put the ui images under `public/stylesheets/images`. That way upgrading the jQuery UI stylesheet is easier, you can just swap it out with your new one.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps just try linking to the image directly in your CSS file but leave the files where they are. If I'm correct, it should know to look in the assets/images folder anyways.

Instead of...

`url(../images/ui-bg_inset-hard_100_fcfdfd_1x100.png)`

Try just

`url(ui-bg_inset-hard_100_fcfdfd_1x100.png)`